# Creating CosmosDb DataSource on Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are trying to create a CosmosDb data source in Azure Search to connect to it later on with an indexer.

However, when trying to create the data source, I get a cryptic error message without code:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid. Details: dataSource : Cannot create an abstract class.\r\n"
    }
}
```

Here is the PUT request sent to azure search (the api-key and connection strings have been verified as correct):

```
{
    "name": "datasourceName",
    "description": "Data source on CosmosDb collection x and partition y",
    "type": "documentdb",
    "credentials": {
        "connectionString": "***"
    },
    "container": {
        "name": "collectionName",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Culture = 'y' AND c.Id LIKE 'prefix%'"
    },
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
        "highWaterMarkColumnName": "_ts"
    }
}
```

The URL used for that request is:

```
https://<servicename>.windows.net/datasources/<datasourceName>?api-version=2017-11-11-Preview
```

I could not find anything in the documentation about creating data sources responses and some guidance would be welcome.

Regards

Comment: Please show the URI of your PUT request

Comment: @EugeneShvets thanks for the quick followup, I edited the post to include the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's responses.

To stay consistent with the question (`PUT` not `POST` request) I'm posting the answer as it's a mix of feedback from the previous answers and comments.

So after adding:

```
"@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy"
```

To the `dataChangeDetectionPolicy` json object (when sending the `PUT` request to Azure Search) and after adding the `Database` part in the connectionString it now works.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `OData type` for the change detection policy:

{
    "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
    "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "[a row version or last_updated column name]"
}

Comment: Okay thanks so when adding the `OData type` I get another error with no code:
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred."
    }
}`

Comment: In case of a useless error message like this, you should open a support ticket so the team can get involved and investigate on the service end (and hopefully improve the error message as well).

Comment: One thing worth trying: change the SQL query to include your collection name: `SELECT * FROM collection_name c ...`

Comment: Did you include the Database as part of your connection string?  See the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb#use-rest-apis

Comment: Thanks @CareyMacDonald that was the missing piece. I posted an answer to summarize these in case someone else comes across this error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete [dataChangeDetectionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models?view=azure-dotnet) in `post` request which is `Abstract base class for data change detection policies`.

Also as Carey MacDonald said, in [connectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb#2---create-a-data-source), don't forget add the `Database` part.

Here is snapshot:
[image]

Comment: In our case we want to keep the `dataChangeDetectionPolicy` and we also want to update an existing data source so we have to use `PUT`and not `POST`. Turns out the Database part of the connection string was the missing piece.